# How to fix error in Codeigniter when making ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY query?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

friends I hope you can help me I am having a problem in this consultation, I have done it in different ways but I always have the same error. The only way I found to avoid the error is deactivating the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY variable of mysql, please somebody knows how to make my query work without having to deactivate the varible, I thank you

```
function get_chart_income()
{
 $this->db->select('SUM(income.amount) AS chart_total_income, income.created_at'); 
 $this->db->group_by('DATE_FORMAT(income.created_at, "%Y-%m")');
 $this->db->order_by('income.created_at ASC');
 $this->db->limit(9);
 return $this->db->get('income')->result_array();


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rcB5.jpg)

Comment: Hello!  would you mind adding the error that you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to aggregate by year and month alone, then it does not make sense to be selecting the full date, which would also include a day (and possibly time) component.  The reason this does not make sense is that it is not clear to MySQL *which* day you want to select (a given year and month can have many different day values).  Most likely, the proper fix here is to just select the same call to `DATE_FORMAT` which appears in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
function get_chart_income() {
    $sql <- "SUM(income.amount) AS chart_total_income, DATE_FORMAT(income.created_at, '%Y-%m') AS created_at";
    $this->db->select($sql);
    $this->db->group_by('created_at');
    $this->db->order_by('created_at');
    $this->db->limit(9);
    return $this->db->get('income')->result_array();
}
```